# How would you translate the sentence "Some philosophers love all philosophers, only if they love themselves"

Tags: logic

I have it as:

((x)(Px&Lxx))>(($y)(x)(Py&(Pz>Lyz))

Where P is a philosopher
L is loves

(Predicate logic)

Comment: Sorry brackets might be in the wrong places

Comment: Not enough detail of self effort

Comment: How about : (there exists x)  (for all y) xLy --> xLx  .   Here, xLy is the "x loves y" relation and x, y are philosophers.  The statement seems to be tautological.

Comment: Further to my comment above, I believe that your translation is equivalent to "some philosophers love all philosophers IF the love themselves", not "ONLY IF".  Note that the statement "A if B" translates to "B --> A", while "A only if B" translates to "A --> B".  I think the statement is tautological since, if a philosopher loves all philosophers, then by definition she must love herself because she is a philosopher.

Comment: "They love themselves" in modern English should mean "Each loves himself", or "The group of philosophers loves itself"  or "Each member of the group of philosophers loves all of the others", because the second 'philosophers' is a more immediate antecedent.  But the comma isolates the pronoun from its logical antecedent, leading us to guess that "they" property binds to the first instance of 'philosophers' and the implication might lie within the quantification.  So this can be a bunch of different logical statements, none quite clear.

Comment: Sorry I realised the actual question was 'Some philosophers love all philosophers only if some philosophers love themselves.'

Comment: The logical form, I think is ($x)(Px&(x)(Py>Lxy))>($x)(Px>Lxx)

Comment: If your question is incorrect,  *then edit it*.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, but to me "They love themselves" can't be interpreted as "The group of philosophers loves itself", or at least in a question like this it is highly unlikely that anything like that is meant.

Comment: @Johannes One can love philosophers in general without loving each individual philosopher, loving each member insofar as they attain to some definition of being a philosopher. As one can love candy without loving each and every form of what is considered candy.  What English means is not determined by philosophical convenience, but by usage.

Comment: Yes, that I don't dispute, but I thought you meant "the group loves philosphers, as a group". I don't think that is sensible because loving is not a group act. But regarding your interpretation "all philosophers love philosophers in general" how would you say that in predicate logic?

Comment: @ jobermark my question was not really related to the original question by JayneEyre, I was just wondering how would reference to groups be formalized, for example when on might say: "Jack loves philosophers (as a group)".

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't even try to translate it, because it is grammatically unclear, and the meaning of the word "they" is unclear, so I wouldn't think I can make any reasonable assumption what it is supposed to mean.

Two reasonable ways to clarify: "Some philosophers love all those philosophers who love themselves, but not those who don't love themselves" and "Some philosophers love all philosophers, but any philosopher can only love all philosophers if that particular philosopher loves himself or herself".

Answer (score 1):

Let us reformulate the proposition first for the clarity's sake:

1. Some philosophers love all philosophers, only if they love themselves
2. If any philosopher loves herself, then there exists at least one philosopher who would love her too.

Let *P(x) = x is a philosopher* and *L(xy) = x loves y*.

Then it seems that we have:

(x)([P(x) -> L(xx)] -> ∃y [P(y) & L(yx)])

Comment: apparently this assumes a single specific meaning where many meanings are possible?

Answer (score 1):

So in the comment you change your question. Now your question is how to formalize:

**(1)** Some philosophers love all philosophers only if some philosophers love themselves.

In fact this is also ambiguous, it has two interpretations:

**(2a)** (Some philosophers love all philosophers) only if (some philosophers love themselves)

or

**(2b)** Some philosophers are such that ((they love all philosophers) only if (some philosophers love themselves))

In the first interpretation, the implication has wider scope.

These are not equivalent. It's easy to see that (2a) is a logically true: Assume that some philosophers love all philosophers, therefore they love themselves, therefore some philosophers love themselves.
On the other hand (2b) is not logically true: just take a model where there are no philosophers, now (2b) is false.

Little more formally (2a) and (2b) are (assuming that "some philosophers" means "there exists at least one philosopher"):

**(3a)** (There exists at least one philosopher who loves all philosophers) only if (there exists at least one philosopher who loves itself)

**(3b)** There exists at leas one philosopher such that ((it loves all philosophers) only if (there exists at least one philosopher who loves itself)

Formalizing these:

**(3a)*** {Ex[P(x) & (y)(P(y)-->L(x,y))]}-->{Ex(P(x) & L(x,x))}

**(3b)*** Ex{(P(x)) & [(y)(P(y)-->L(x,y))-->Ez(P(z) & L(z,z))]}

If we had taken "some philosophers" to mean that "there exist at least two philosophers" this would have to be modified.

In speech those two interpretations of (1) could be represented by different speech patterns: e.g. in the first interpretation you put a long pause before and after the "only if", in the second interpretation you put a long pause after the first "some philosophers".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to try translating the formula; as there have been good efforts by others; but I want to point out that *some* could be formalised by what is called a plural quantifier; and this might allow keeping some of the ambiguities in the phrase; which after all, it can be argued, is part of its meaning